# Warnings in Emacs: Internal native compiler error failed to compile

Tags: emacs

I am a beginner in *Emacs*. After installing the *SLIME* environment, I keep receiving the following warnings when I open *Emacs*:

```
Warning (comp): c:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-28.2/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/pp.el: Error: Internal native compiler error failed to compile Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (comp): c:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-28.2/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/progmodes/project.el: Error: Internal native compiler error failed to compile Disable showing Disable logging
Warning (comp): c:/Program Files/Emacs/emacs-28.2/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/progmodes/gud.el: Error: Internal native compiler error failed to compile Disable showing Disable logging
```

**Are they crucial and how should I deal with them?**

I searched the internet regaring the warnings but I failed to get useful information. Moreover, I do not experience any crucial errors when I test basic *Lisp* programming in *Emacs* though.

Comment: FYI [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/1319821). And welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I keep receving the following warning as I open emacs. Are they crucial ...?

They are not crucial in a sense these errors don't prevent `Emacs` from working, which you confirmed yourself. But if you don't like error messages and like (significantly) faster-working `Emacs`, then let's move on to

> how should I deal with them?

Probably start with reading a few paragraphs: <kbd>M-:</kbd> (info "(elisp) Native Compilation") <kbd>RET</kbd> or in [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Native-Compilation.html), to get an overall understanding what the error message is about. Namely:

> In addition to the byte-compilation, described in the previous
> chapter, Emacs can also optionally compile Lisp
> function definitions into a true compiled code, known as “native
> code”. This feature uses the ‘libgccjit’ library, which is part of the
> GCC distribution, and requires that Emacs be built with support for
> using that library.  It also requires to have GCC and Binutils (the
> assembler and linker) available on your system for you to be able to
> native-compile Lisp code.

From this text, we can understand that the error reported means `Emacs` couldn't (natively) compile the files. And our first look should probably be towards checking if `libgccjit` library can be used by `Emacs`.

I guess the following EmacsSE threads: [‘Error: junk at end of line’ with native-comp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71321/28451) and [Is there a gccemacs (native-comp) build for MS-Windows?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62482/28451) may provide helpful info for your case.

If that doesn't help, post more info on which way was your `Emacs` installed/compiled, more details about your environment, and output of <kbd>M-:</kbd> (native-comp-available-p) <kbd>RET</kbd>.

And, in a case you're a type of person who likes diving into more details, the article [Bringing GNU Emacs to Native Code](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.02504.pdf) could be invaluable.